# ng-repeat showing functions names and data

Tags: mongodb, angularjs, mlab

I'm a beginner with angularjs and mongolab ..

I have this code, to edit a record in mongolab :

```
function EditCtrl($scope, $location, $routeParams, Project) {
    var self = this;
    Project.get({id: $routeParams.projetId}, function(projet) {
        self.original = projet;
        $scope.projet = new Project(self.original);
    });

    $scope.save = function() {
        $scope.projet.update(function() {
            $location.path('/list');
        });
    };
}
```

It works perfectly.
I wanted to display all the keys and values from the record, this is the code :

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in projet">
    <div>{{key}}:{{val}}</div>
</div>
```

And this is the result :

_id:{}
destroy:
name:Test test
rang:4
update:

In my record, i only have the _id, name and rang. I don't know why "destroy:" dans "update:" are displayed! probably because i use this code to connect to mongolab :

```
angular.module('mongolab', ['ngResource']).
        factory('Project', function($resource) {
    var Project = $resource('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases' +
            '/_____/collections/_________/:id',
            {apiKey: '___________________'}, {
        update: {method: 'PUT'}
    }
    );

    Project.prototype.update = function(cb) {
        return Project.update({id: this._id.$oid},
        angular.extend({}, this, {_id: undefined}), cb);
    };

    Project.prototype.destroy = function(cb) {
        return Project.remove({id: this._id.$oid}, cb);
    };

    return Project;
});
```

What should i do to only display the record data ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return  a service and pass the item you receive from get() back to update and destroy.

```
factory('Project', function($resource) {
return { 
     get: function() {
         return $resource('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases' +
        '/_____/collections/_________/:id',
        {apiKey: '___________________'}, {
         update: {method: 'PUT'}
      },


update : function(itm, cb) {
    return item.update({id: item._id.$oid},
    angular.extend({}, item, {_id: undefined}), cb);
},

destroy : function(item, cb) {
    return item.remove({id: item._id.$oid}, cb);
};
```

Otherwise you can instantiate only one and reference it

```
factory('Project', function($resource) {
var item =$resource('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases' +
        '/_____/collections/_________/:id',
        {apiKey: '___________________'}, {
         update: {method: 'PUT'}
return { 


update : function(cb) {
    return item.update({id: item._id.$oid},
    angular.extend({}, item, {_id: undefined}), cb);
},

destroy : function(cb) {
    return item.remove({id: item._id.$oid}, cb);
};
```

Comment: Sorry i'm a beginner i just didn't understand your solution, i tried it but a got some js errors like : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function for the line `update : function(item, cb) {`

Comment: provide a plunkr / jsfiddle and I will try to modify it. (you can mock the mongo call)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/vGmB12hrEW0Hdde3zagF?p=preview click on "Editer" and you'll see the problem i talked about. Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/3oLkaerGUQSt86OyWDtl?p=preview the tricky part is that you have the name "Project" both as a remote domain object and as an AngularJs Service. The plnkr works though.

Comment: I just remarqued that the edit function doesn't work anymore ? i got this error : TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'update'